# C inline asm for x86 in / out port I/O has operand-size mismatch

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm following a tutorial on youtube and he said that it's needed to write some asm code in C (i'm not very good in assembly) so i just coped the entire code:

```
unsigned char inPortB (unsigned int _port) {
    unsigned char rv;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (rv) : "dN" (_port));
    return rv;
}
```

and

```
void outPortB (unsigned int _port, unsigned char _data) {
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %1, %0" : :  "dN" (_port), "a" (_data));
}
```

but when i compile i get this error:

```
operand type mismatch for 'in'
operand type mismatch for 'out'
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Surely this is not your entire code.  Can you show us what your whole function looks like? I'm especially interested in the types of `_port` and `_data`.

Comment: @fuz Sure. I also don't get why it cause a problem even if i don't call those functios...

Comment: You get an assembler error because the compiler emits code for these functions and the assembly it generates is defective.  The compiler is obliged to generate code for functions with global linkage as other translation units might call them.

Comment: If you are coding on Linux, consider using the `inb()` and `outb()` functions from `<sys/io.h>`.

Comment: Don't try learning C or Assembler from obscure YT videos. Get a good textbook. On a sidenote: No halfway rmodern Dektop/Server OS will allow IO access for userspace code. For drivers, use the OS providesd mechanisms. Even on bare-metal, there is hardly need for a beginner to use inline Assembler. Most platforms provide intrinsics.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite : For performance reasons Linux has the `sys_iopl` and `sys_ioperm` system calls that allow user space programs running with root privileges direct access to ports on Linux running on x86 platforms (via IO privileges in the process' TSS). XServers running in user mode may rely on this for doing 8514 graphics output.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: 1) As you write, these are system calls, i.e. no direct machine instructions and 2) they are not allowed by default for good reasons. I'm not sure, but I could think they require appropriate capabilities enabled for the program.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite `sys_iopl` and `sys_ioperm` tell x86 Linux (assuming one is running as root privs) that `in` and `out` instructions will allow direct port access in Linux user mode (ring3) without causing a #GP. This feature is supported in x86 hardware with the IO privilege bitmap in the Task State Segment or if CPL<=IOPL. This effectively allows the `in` and `out` port instructions  (and all related port instructions) to run as non-privileged instructions on specific ports (or on all of them).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ah, I see. Nevertheless, it is not available for normal user code and not allowewd by default. Actually I consider such code (and the option alone) very problematic. As modern hardware (including x86) uses mostly MMIO, it''s also not so very useful except for legacy stuff. Finally: OP does not mention the OP and I somewhat suspect it's some DOS/Win95/98 stuff originally. Not using fixed width types as would be correct supports this imo. But enough speculation.

Comment: @G.Sliepen : That might seem like a good idea, but after reviewing the GLIBC code in that header (even the latest version they have in GIT), it would be too buggy for me to seriously consider in a real project. I was pretty shocked when I opened sys/io.h and looked at the code. Whatever you do, don't compile it with optimizations on.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: `sys/io.h` looks ok on my desktop.  It looks like it matches fuz's answer.  (https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/sys/io.h.html).  Did you think there should be a `"memory"` clobber to take advantage of the runtime memory-barrier effect? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile says `asm volatile` can reorder relative to other compiler-generated code (a problem for setting FP rounding mode, but not for normal device-driver use).  I think it's treated like other `volatile` accesses, which can't reorder with each other.

Comment: @PeterCordes GLIBC sys/io.h is meant to be used in user mode (or kernel mode). The obvious error is passing a pointer to an array through a register for the functions with __addr (both input and output). You end up with crap like this generated: https://godbolt.org/z/8xj-q- . So yes, the missing `memory` or a dummy memory operand are missing (the godbolt code has a a couple variants showing how you can fix it). The functions without the `__addr` parameter are fine

Comment: @PeterCordes : At least the Linux kernel  `io.h` didn't botch it (they use `memory` clobber) for those functions that are reading/writing an array. We've discussed this particular issue with inline assembly in the past. One of those reasons why inline assembly is bad if you don't know all the nuances.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Oops I meant to post this version: https://godbolt.org/z/Gvudoi

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Oh, I was only looking at the defs for `inb`, not the `rep`-string version.  Yes, that's horrible!  You should have said in your earlier comment that it was only those that were unsafe, because there's nothing wrong with their `inb` and `outb` definitions, and that's what the OP of this question is using.

Comment: @PeterCordes : my comment was not directed to the OP but to the person who suggested a general fix to use `io.h` from glibc. My comment was in the context of using that file in general, not specifically for the case of the function the OP is using (which isn't a problem). My comment is basically saying if you value your sanity until the bugs are fixed avoid it especially if you intend to use any of the functions (especially with optimizations on) that pass an array via the `__addr` parameter don't use GLIBC as a template for proper code. The Linux kernel's io.h is properly done.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: well in my defence I only suggested using `inb()` and `outb()` from that header file. But thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The port number needs to be in `dx` which is a 16 bit register.  To make gcc generate a reference to `dx` instead of `edx` as it does with your code, you need to give `_port` a 16 bit type, e.g. `unsigned short`:

```
unsigned char inPortB (unsigned short _port) {
    unsigned char rv;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (rv) : "dN" (_port));
    return rv;
}
```

This should fix your issues.